# Lamba expression in a razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Can somebody help me on the Lambda expression.

My ModelVM looks like :

```
namespace MReports.Models
{
    public class FullDetailVM
    {
        public FullDetailVM()
        {
            DetailSet = new List<FullDetailSet>();
        }
    ........
        public List<FullDetailSet> DetailSet { get; set; }
    }

    public class FullDetailSet
    {
        public FullDetailSet(){    }    
        public string Mnum { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string LabelValue { get; set; }             
    }
}
```

Data in the above model will be :

```
DetailSet[0] = {1,"MCity","LosAngeles"}
DetailSet[0] = {1,"MState","California"}
DetailSet[0] = {1,"MZip","90045"}
DetailSet[0] = {1,"MStreet","Cardiff"}
DetailSet[0] = {1,"MHouse No","1234"}
DetailSet[0] = {1,"MApt","1"}
```

View(Razor) :

```
@model MReports.Models.FullDetailVM
@if(Model != null)
{
<div class="row contentHeaderInfo">
 <ul class="list-inline">
<li> City :
</li>
<li>
//Display LabelValue corresponding to Mcity 
   Model.DetailSet.select(LabelValue).Where(Label== "Mcity");       
</li>
<li> State:
</li>
<li>
//Display LabelValue corresponding to MState 
   Model.DetailSet.select(LabelValue).Where(Label== "MState");       
</li>
</ul>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lambda** expressions can be used to create delegate types. I've found the easiest way to explain this to someone is to show them a list of items, such as your `List<FullDetailSet> DetailSet`, and ask them what items from that list do you want based on a specific condition?

If you wanted all the items with label "Dog" you would do something like this:

```
Model.DetailSet.Where(d => d.Label == "Dog").Select(d => d.Value);
```

This will go over the items in `DetailSet` and check if each item has a `Label` of "Dog". For lack of a better understanding on the correct terminology, you are iterating over that list and grabbing what you need based on your conditions. This is why I used `d` as the placeholder, to me it looks as though `d` is a singluar representation of `DetailSet`.

If you needed only one record from that `DetailSet` you would use `Single` over `Where`.

```
Model.DetailSet.Single(d => d.Label == "Dog").Select(d => d.Value);
```

If you didn't need just the `Value` of those records that met your conditions you can grab the entire list like this:

```
Model.DetailSet.Where(d => d.Label == "Dog").ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Model.DetailSet.Where(x=>x.Label == "Mcity").Select(x=>x.LabelValue)
```

or if you have just one recors Label == Mcity

```
  Model.DetailSet.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Label == "Mcity").LabelValue
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select one record using `Single`, then just get the property.

```
Model.DetailSet.Single(m => m.Label == "MState").LabelValue
```